# UICollectionViewCell rotation with resizing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm using storyboard and I have UICollectionViewController. According to current design I need to make different cell sizes for landscape and portrait orientation.

So I've impemented:

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout  *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        // Adjust cell size for orientation
        if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation])) {
            return CGSizeMake(133.f, 110.f);
        }
        return CGSizeMake(152.f, 126.f);
}
```

I don't have autolayout for this project. The question is how to resize cells' elements so they fit it smaller cell. Currently content doesn't fit.

Cell's `- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame` doesn't get called, because I use storyboard for cell design